# Prevent onClick to fire on disabled span

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component which has a span to trigger an action.

```
<span
  className="btn badge"
  onClick={() => alert('Added!')}
  disabled={this.props.enabled !== true}
>
   <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
</span>
```

Now even if the `disabled` condition is true, I see the disabled cursor on the span but clicking on it actually fires the onClick event, which is unexpected. No event should be fired for disabled element. Using `<button>` instead of span seems to work good.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `disabled` only on select HTML elements.
Here is a list https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

Comment: disabled is attribute of form elements in html, such as input, button, select, textarea. please don't use click on span, div, p or ... because also it have accessibility issue for disabled people, it's not focusable and etc.

Comment: Which `ReactJS` version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using disabled prop use styles to show disabled

```
<span
  className={`btn badge ${!this.props.enabled && disabledClass}`}
  onClick={this.props.enabled && (() => alert('Added!'))}
 >
 <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
```

or even better for semantic and accessibility purpose.

```
<button
 className="btn badge"
 onClick={() => alert('Added!')}
 disabled={this.props.enabled !== true}
>
  <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
</button>
```

I didn't test it but It should work.

Comment: Yes I can definitely do this but why does disabled span triggers an onClick event?

Comment: Like Utsav Patel said in the comment that you can only use it on form HTML elements and span is not form element.